# Properly handling transient entities in NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, transient, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

What's the proper way to reference entities which were already persisted in a different session, but remained unchanged in memory after a session has been closed?

Once NH persists an entity in a single session and that session is closed, I need to fetch it again in a new session in order to reference it in some other transient entities. Or, I can call `Session.Lock` on the new session instance and let NH know this entity is not transient. This item should never change during app lifetime.

What would be the preferred way to use? Is there some other way to do it?

**[Edit]**

Additional problem is that I am using the Repository pattern, and not using NH directly in my business layer. This means that I also need to have a way to abstract this call to Session.Lock, i.e. have a method similar to Session.Lock in my repository interface. This is a bit smelly IMHO.

Comment: Why do you keep entities in memory after the session is closed? I never needed to do that.

Comment: @Paco: I create lots of new entities which reference existing, already persisted entities.

Comment: I mean why do you keep them in memory instead of retrieving them from the database? Won't this cause a corrupt database when a transaction fails?

Comment: @Paco: I am only keeping several long lived entities, which never actually change in db, simply to avoid retrieving them on each insert. Why do you think I could end up with a corrupt database?

Comment: When a transaction fails, and the data you write is different from the data you read, you can have a problem. Using the second level cache like Jamie Ide suggest, will make your code less complex and your transactions safe.

Comment: @Paco: I still don't get it. If I (for example) read a City entity from a database at application start, and it never changes neither in db nor in memory, and then Insert a bunch of Person entities which reference this same City entity (and repeat these batch inserts often), how will the 2nd level cache help me if Insert fails? If I simply keep the City entity in memory, since it is a NH proxy which *knows* it has been persisted, I can reference this object from other entities without NH complaining that it is a transient entity.

Comment: When it really 100% never changes, you probably can not have a corruption problem. I would still go for the second level cache, because what you call "in memory" is a second level cache, but than more difficult to use than the real ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the first question. **If you are just going to read the entity, you don't have to do anything.** Even assigning it as a field to a different entity will not require you to lock the record. The only reason you need to call `ISession.Lock` is when you want to mutate and then save the entity.

**There is an exception and that is lazy loading.** If the entity has foreign child records that were not loaded while the first session was active, an exception will be thrown when you try to access them later on. The easiest way to get around is, is to touch the child collections in first session.

If the entity is still giving you problems under these circumstances, you can add a `Load` to your repository. You can wire this to `ISession.Load`. What `Load` does is create an empty proxy for the entity without hitting the database. This entity is a part of the session the entity is loaded with and can be used to assign to properties of other entities. The advantage of this approach is that it's a lot cleaner and it's easy to mock with unit testing.

Concerning the second question. Yes, you're right that it smells to integrate `ISession.Lock` into a repository. Again, when you don't have to mutate the entity, you don't have to worry about this. But, when you are, well, you really should think about just re-loading the entity from the repository and work on that one. I know it's not as optimal as could be, but it saves you a lot of very strange code, specifically in your unit tests.

One last thing. I understand that you're talking about an entity that will live for a long time (maybe the full runtime of the application). You have roughly three categories of lifetime: 1. forever, 2. long and 3. short. The reason I mention this is that more than once, problems with entities that have a 'long' lifetime could really just stay connected to a session that has the same lifetime. **It's not a problem to have a session alive for say, 5 or 10 minutes (the time the user is entering data in a form).** This alone will save most people a lot of trouble.

One more note: have a look at [`NHibernateUtil`](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Project/NHibernate/3.0.0.Alpha1/Release/All/NHibernate/NHibernate/Util/ReflectHelper.cs) and [`NHibernateProxyHelper`](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Project/NHibernate/3.0.0.Alpha1-4950/Release/All/NHibernate/NHibernate/Proxy/NHibernateProxyHelper.cs). These classes can help you force loading of entities and child collections.

Comment: Thanks. This entity **is** long-lived (through entire app lifetime), and most new entities that will be persisted need to reference this entity. So, whenever I create a new session in order to save these new entities, I need to tell NH that this object was already persisted - otherwise it complains that it's a transient object.

Comment: An alternative is to add `Load` methods to your repositories with in turn call `Load` on the session. Then you can load the entity in the current session by its ID. The thing about `Load` is that it does not hit the database but creates a proxy with only the ID. This way you can re-fetch the object without actually fetching it. When unit testing, this is a lot easier and cleaner to fake. Updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, it seems I was doing something wrong, because you are right: If I am not changing the entity, and I assign it to a different entity, I don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is to enable second level caching and make the object eligible for caching. If you do this, you can fetch it in your repository methods but it will be fetched from cache instead of the database.

Comment: Thanks, thats a neat idea also. Do you have a recommendation on which 2nd level cache provider I should use?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server I would start with SysCache2 because it supports SqlDependencies. Not that I've ever needed that functionality.

Comment: It's been a while since the last reaction, but I just like to second that SysCache2 is awesome, but also that Second Level Caching is a pretty obscure feature when it comes to documentation. One great tip: if you configure VS right, you get to debug NH which can really be enlightening if you're not sure what's happening: http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio